# Flexbox columns and rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use CSS3 flexbox on my site with limited success.

I can create a lovely 3 column layout, but I want the third column to wrap under the second column at a certain screen resolution. Is this possible using flexbox, or do I have to revert to more traditional methods?

My code is at http://jsfiddle.net/eFeC3/, which shows how my code currently looks as well as the flexbox implementation.

```
<style>
body > * > *{background:#666;color:#eee;padding:40px;margin:20px;text-align:center;}
/* Flex */
article{display:-webkit-flex}
section{-webkit-flex:1;-webkit-order:2}
nav{-webkit-order:1}
aside{-webkit-order:3}

/* Nasty */
#b, #c {overflow:hidden}
#a{float:left;margin:0px 40px 80px 20px}
</style>
<body>
   <article>
      <section>1</section>
      <aside>2</aside>
      <nav>3</nav>
    </article>

<div id="demo">
    <div id="a">3</div>
    <div id="b">1</div>
    <div id="c">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear as to how you want your elements to lay out?  The way you have your elements reordered (3 1 2), wrapping elements would cause 2 to be under 3.  You would have to use a media query here to correct the order.  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/Axutc

Comment: The order is already changed by the -webkit-order property. The idea is say at 800px you have 3 columns, 600px you have two (the nav is the first and the other elements are the second) and then you have one column at 400px (elements stacked on top of each other). This kind of happens with the demo you showed (which uses the older version of flexbox), but is width dependent rather than being forced by the css

Comment: My demo is not using an older version of Flexbox, it is providing all properties necessary for maximum browser support.

Comment: Apologies, I looked at it more hurriedly than perhaps I should have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex elements don't wrap by default.  When you're making use of wrapping, it works best if you also specify a `flex-basis` to say *this is the ideal width for this element*.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/Axutc

```
article {
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section {
  -webkit-flex: 1 20em;
  -ms-flex: 1 20em;
  flex: 1 20em;
  -webkit-flex-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}

nav {
  -webkit-flex: 1 10em;
  -ms-flex: 1 10em;
  flex: 1 10em;
  /* by default, flex elements have an order of 0 */
}

aside {
  -webkit-flex: 1 10em;
  -ms-flex: 1 10em;
  flex: 1 10em;
  -webkit-flex-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}
```

If the elements need to be reordered at a specific break point, then your only option is to use media queries.  You can also use media queries to change the `flex-basis` to a percentage if you're dissatisfied with where it chooses to wrap on its own (eg. `flex: 1 20%`).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for Firefox: all three containers end up in the same row.

Comment: The Mozilla team willfully chose to release their standard Flexbox implementation in an incomplete state (it was hidden behind a configuration setting when this answer was written).  Wrapping is not supported, and you'll need to use a feature query to hide `display: flex` from Firefox.